# What's the field dataFileVersion that appears in db.stats()?

Tags: mongodb

When I run `db.stats()`, there's a field named `dataFileVersion`, with major and minor. What means this field, and why it has two versions? I have to fix it in some way?

```
{
"db" : "xxxxxx",
"collections" : 4,
"objects" : 1419385,
"avgObjSize" : 1053.0462164951723,
"dataSize" : 1494678004,
"storageSize" : 1773617152,
"numExtents" : 30,
"indexes" : 2,
"indexSize" : 46063584,
"fileSize" : 6373244928,
"nsSizeMB" : 16,
"dataFileVersion" : {
    "major" : 4,
    "minor" : 5
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataFileVersion` contains the version number of the on-disk format of the data files for the database.  In this case it indicates a version of `4.5`.

Documentation [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/dbStats/#dbStats.dataFileVersion).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I read the documentation but I didn't understand that is notation for 4.5. About the "version number of the on-disk format", what that means? Thanks again.

Comment: @raulmarcosl It's the version number of MongoDB's internal format for structuring the files on disk that contain the database.